# Installing Smalltalk project from GitHub Repository

Tags: github, smalltalk, squeak, metacello

First of all: I never worked with Smalltalk before, so it's a bit of a culture shock for me. I am using Squeak 5.1 (32bit).

Now to my question: I want to install a Smalltalk project from a GitHub Repository. I successfully installed Metacello using this code, executing it in Transcript:

```
"Get the Metacello configuration (for Squeak users)"
Installer gemsource
    project: 'metacello';
    addPackage: 'ConfigurationOfMetacello';
    install.

"Bootstrap Metacello Preview, using mcz files (#'previewBootstrap' symbolic version"
((Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfMetacello) project 
  version: #'previewBootstrap') load.

"Load the Preview version of Metacello from GitHub"
(Smalltalk at: #Metacello) new
  configuration: 'MetacelloPreview';
  version: #stable;
  repository: 'github://dalehenrich/metacello-work:configuration';
  load.

"Now load latest version of Metacello"
(Smalltalk at: #Metacello) new
  baseline: 'Metacello';
  repository: 'github://dalehenrich/metacello-work:master/repository';
  get.
(Smalltalk at: #Metacello) new
  baseline: 'Metacello';
  repository: 'github://dalehenrich/metacello-work:master/repository';
  load.
```

And I also installed the Metacello Scripting API using this code:

```
Installer gemsource
    project: 'metacello';
    install: 'ConfigurationOfMetacello'.
```

If I now want to install a project from a GitHub Repository, for example this:

```
Metacello new
  baseline: 'Animations';
  repository: 'github://hpi-swa/animations/repository';
  load.
```

Then I allways get this error:

```
gofer repository error: 'GoferRepositoryError: UndefinedObject>>thisOSProcess'...ignoring
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The `OSProcess` package appears to be missing. What OS are you working on?

Comment: I've repeated the same steps you describe in a brand new installation for the Mac and it worked just fine.

Comment: @MaxLeske I am working on Windows and I use the All-in-One Version of Squeak (which should run on Windows, Mac and Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right, that doesn't work. OSProcess is has not yet been marked as compatible with Squeak 5.1 and even if it were, it's not being pulled in by Metacello. I'll report this to the developers.

In the mean time you can load OSProcess with

```
(Installer ss project: 'OSProcess') install: 'OSProcess-dtl.98'
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot. Now I'm able to load the repo given above. Do you have an idea how to load this [repo](https://github.com/matthias-springer/space-cleanup)? It seems to miss a BaselineOf directory.

Comment: Space Cleanup isn't a Metacello-Project. You should do this: (1) clone the repo; (2) Add a Monticello Filetree repository in Squeak and use the 'packages' directory of the repo (3) load the packages manually via monticello (alphabetic order seems fine here)

Comment: @Tobias Thx for the instruction :)